# I just opened someone's Flutter Project in my android studio and Got this Error. Help me fixing it

Tags: flutter, exception, mobile, error-handling, sdk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Toshiba.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Toshiba.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set `compileSDKVersion` and `targetSDKVersion` to 31 in android>app>build.gradle as shown in the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/9x9GVNGzfRUf)

If you still get any errors, kindly update the kotlin version in android>build.gradle as shown in the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/FZmLVdTF_ATL)